# proguard not working in Eclipse mac: Unable to access jarfile /Volumes/New

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I created a new test project in latest ADT and all updated sources in Eclipse and have edited **project.properties** and **proguard-project.text** 
And I get the following error in console in mac:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Unable to access jarfile /Volumes/New
```

How do I resolve it I have tried everything? But still get the error in mac!

**proguard-project.text**

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
# -optimizationpasses 5
# -allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

**project.properties**

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
```

Comment: Created test project, updated proguard-project.text, project.properties - all is ok for me. So ... 1.please open console, run env command and provide me with output. 2. open eclipse settings/Android and provide me  with your "SDK location".

Comment: SDK Location is : /Volumes/New Volume E/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk   And secondly where should I type env in terminal or somewhere in eclipse?? Thank You again for your time and effort

Comment: After typing env in terminal this is what I get: THe Result is displayed above.

Comment: After dragging the location to terminal where proguard android is located this is displayed : usernames-MacBook-Pro:New Volume D username$ /Volumes/New\ Volume\ E/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

edit your ~/.profile  file (add the following lines at the end of file)

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Volumes/New\ Volume\ E/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
export PATH=ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$PATH
```

really not sure you need ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools, but for sure ...

restart ADT (not sure if you have to logout/login your account, do this if necessary)

hope this help

one more comment: try to move SDK to native Mac volume if it is possible

**EDIT:**
`~/.profile` --> **~** is synonim to your home dir e.g. `/Users/<your_user_name>`
.profile is hidden file

Comment: I did not find .profile file in /users/ but its there in etc/profile is that corrent ??

Comment: Can I copy and paste the entire adt-bundle-mac-x86_64 folder to root directory ?? Will I have any errors ??

Comment: You can copy bundle to your home directory

Comment: I tried everything you have suggested still getting the same error

Comment: I have created a new folder (Untitled Folder) under main harddisk/users/user/untitled folder/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64  .Will this work ??

Comment: ,profile file is nott present I used defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

Comment: I can see .bash History but no profile in /Users/<your_user_name>

Comment: ok, let you user name on this computer is mrX - so full path to .profile is : /Users/mrX/.profile

Comment: >>>>>I have created a new folder (Untitled Folder) under main harddisk/users/user/untitled folder/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64 .Will this work ??<<<<< please use folder name without spaces if possible

Comment: and if there is no .profile in  /Users/mrX --> just create this file with content i suggest and add executable attribute to it

Comment: I have tried both the solutions : I created .profile and restarted the mac .Still same error . I also tried moving the file to home directory I get :    Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: proguard/ProGuard
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: proguard.ProGuard
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)

Comment: And if I copy and paste the entire folder I get : failed to find a main class in org.eclipse.equinox.launcher when I open eclipse !!!!!!

Comment: I will accept the answer provided for all the patience .Please help me get the right answer .Should I reinstall eclipse/android in main volume ????? if nothing works ???

Comment: I have reinstalled everything in main drive and its working now !!

Comment: I wish I could give more points for the answer .THanks again for everything SIR .

Comment: have a nice coding for Android :)

Comment: Thanks I am posting a new question.Please look into it if you have the time .Thanks.